# Getting incorrect results while running linux top command in golang using exec

Tags: linux, go, exec

I am trying to get the top running processes in golang, for which I am running linux top command using golang "os/exec" package but getting discrepancy in the Process name.

Process name is truncated and a "+" suffix is added to the name in golang output. But when running the same command in terminal, it is showing the full process name.

Command: top -b -n 1

I am running the following code:

```
cmd := exec.Command("top","-b","-n","1")
out, err := cmd.Output()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error in running command ", err)
}
fmt.Println(string(out))
```

Expected result: Top running processes with full command name, e.g row:

```
 137295 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/u1:1-writeback
```

Result returned in go output row:

```
 137295 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker+
```

Notice the discrepancy in command name kworker/u4:2-writeback and kworker+

Comment: If you run it in a terminal, `top` can see how wide the display is and adjust its output accordingly. If you're just execing it from another process with output to a pipe, it can't do that and assumes a default width

Answer (score 0):

Basically what Shawn said in the comment. You can even mimic the Go code's behaviour with your code, by resizing the terminal to see the output being truncated and replaced with `+`.

With a full size terminal though, you can still get your Go code to display the same output, as you get by executing it on the terminal directly, by setting the `Stderr` and `Stdout` of the `*exec.Cmd`.

```
    cmd := exec.Command("top", "-b", "-n", "1")
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error in running command ", err)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As Shawn said, top will assume a default width when running from a different process. Explicitly setting the width in the top command worked for me.

```
cmd := exec.Command("top", "-b", "-n", "1", "-w", "100")
```